# Trying to update to PHP 7.4 but getting this error in an element, Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, php-7.3

Hey there I am new here heard a lot about this helpful community. I'm trying to update my custom build a theme to PHP 7.4 but during compatibility testing I found this error, any help would be appreciated.

I have 0 knowledge of PHP (currently)

Here is the code.

```
$type_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID,"property-type" );
$type_count = count($type_terms);
if(!empty($type_terms)){
    echo '<small> - ';
    $loop_count = 1;
    foreach($type_terms as $typ_trm){
        echo $typ_trm->name;
        if($loop_count < $type_count && $type_count > 1){
            echo ', ';
        }
        $loop_count++;
    }
    echo '</small>';
}else{
    echo '&nbsp;';
}
?>
            </span>
        </h5>
    </div>

    <div class="property-meta clearfix">
        <?php
```

Thanks

Comment: that means `get_the_terms` has returned a value which is not an array (e.g. `NULL` or `false`, or a string). Probably, moving `$type_count = count($type_terms);` one line below (under the `if`) would solve the proble

Comment: what is $post in this case ? What you get there ?

Comment: use [`var_dump($some-variable);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) might help in debugging.

Comment: Thanks Everyone learned about get_the_terms alot from here! issue has been resolved thank you all for engaging with question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the WordPress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/) about `get_the_terms` :

> Return: Array of WP_Term objects on success, false, if there are no terms or the post, does not exist, WP_Error on failure.

that means `get_the_terms` function will return 1 of these 3 options :

1. false
2. error
3. array

if the post has some "terms" then you will get no warnings, but it occurs when you try to count some results that are not a valid array (or any countable object).
so you can check for it befor you try to count the fetched terms :

```
if(is_array($type_terms))
   $type_count = count($type_terms);
else 
   $type_count = [];
```

or with ternary operation:

```
$type_count = is_array($type_terms) ? count($type_terms); : [] ;
```